# how to use prototype to avoid copying of functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I had written this code to simulate OOP inheritance and calling baseclass in javascript and it works:

```
function Animal(name,age)
  {
    this._name = name; 
    this.setName = function (name) { this._name = name }
    this.getName = function() { return this._name }
  }

  function Cat(name,age)
  {
    Animal.call(this,name,age); // call baseclass constructor
    this.getName = function() { return Cat.prototype.getName.call(this)+", a cat" }
  }
  Cat.prototype = new Animal(); // will create the baseclass structure

  /// *****  actual execution  *****
  var puss = new Cat("Puss",3);
  var cheshire = new Cat("Cheshire",10);
  // do some actions
  console.log ( puss.getName() );
  // change cat's name
  puss.setName("Puss in boots");
  alert ( "new name -->"+puss.getName() );
```

problem is that, for each instance of "new Cat()" the "getName" and "setName" functions are replicated. 
I have read a lot of articles on prototyping but none addressed the issue of calling the baseclass function.

Comment: This is how JavaScript works! Every newly created object has all properties copied from the prototype. This is normal behaviour, not a problem. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the methods to the prototype of the function, for example,

```
function Animal(name, age) {
    this._name = name;
    this._age = age;
}
Animal.prototype.getName = function () { return this._name; }
Animal.prototype.setName = function (value) { this._name = value; }

function Cat(name, age) {
    Animal.call(this, name, age);
}
Cat.prototype = new Animal();
Cat.prototype.getName = function () { 
    return Animal.prototype.getName.call(this) + ", a cat"; 
}
```

Comment: is there a simple way to prevent the 'constructor' of Animal from running twice?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How is it running twice?

Comment: @NirO. Yes, there is. In ES5 you can use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) (in the browsers that doesn't support it you can use the shim written in the link). So you will have: `Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);`

Comment: @chuckj the first time being
Cat.prototype = new Animal();
and the second:
var c = new Cat("puss",1);

Comment: @NirO As ZER0 indicated you can avoid `new Animal()` by using `Object.create()` or some polyfill of it (see ZER0's link). You just need an object that has the same prototype as an instance created by `Animal()`.

Answer (score 0):

From http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html

> Javascript does not have any sort of 'super' property, which would
>   point to its parent class. Instead, you use the call() method of a
>   Function object, which allows you to run a function using a different
>   object as context for it. If you needed to pass parameters to this
>   function, they would go after the 'this'.

In your case it works the same for functions as "methods", so you can do:

```
Animal.prototype.setName.call(this, name);
```

Comment: gives TypeError: Animal.prototype.getName is undefined

Comment: Sorry, I changed it slightly after I posted. Part of the problem is going to be with your setName and getName methods you defined in the Animal function. Those needs to be prototypes as well. I encourage you to look at the link I provided, as he covers all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `__proto__` which stores prototype data?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto

If you do a `console.log(puss.__proto__.getName)` you'll get what seems to be the "baseclass" function but I'm not sure how cross-browser is this.

Comment: `__proto__` is not accessible in all browsers and should be avoided.

Comment: @FelixKling: Until/unless [standardized](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts)... *"Added section B.3.1 with specifies `__proto__` feature."*